# Minimal angled rectangle enclosing all black pixels of an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I need to get the minimal angled rectangle enclosing all black pixels of an image.

Target images are scanned monochrome comic/manga pages that can be in any position (translated and rotated).

The desired result is similar to the following snippet when all black pixels are connected:

```
_, mono = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(255-mono, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0])
```

In other words, I need to get the `minAreaRect` of the union of all contours, not only for one of them.

How can I do it using Python OpenCV?

Comment: Please show an example of your image!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), "What are good topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How do I ask a good question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 4):

To keep your idea using the contours found by [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0), you just need to merge all of your contours, e.g. using [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html). Since you only need the plain coordinates for [`cv2.minAreaRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9), merging them should be fine. To get the four vertices of the rotated rectangle, use [`cv2.boxPoints`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf78d467e024b4d7936cf9397185d2f5c). Finally, drawing can be done with [`cv2.polylines`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga1ea127ffbbb7e0bfc4fd6fd2eb64263c).

Here's some short code snippet with a minimal example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Some test image
image = 255 * np.ones((300, 300), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(image, (100, 60), 30, 0, 1)
cv2.circle(image, (200, 200), 60, 0, 1)

# Find contours (with respect to OpenCV version); merge them
cnts = cv2.findContours(255-image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = np.vstack(cnts)

# Calculate minAreaRect of merged contours; determine points
pts = np.int32(cv2.boxPoints(cv2.minAreaRect(cnts)))
cv2.polylines(image, [pts], True, 192)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

That'd be the image:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.1.2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Instead of `cv2.polylines` you could also use `cv2.drawContours(image, [pts], -1, (0,0,0), 5)` if you wanted to be able to change the box color and the thickness

Comment: @nathancy Color and thickness can be set in `cv2.polylines`, too - see the linked documentation.